# How do I compile the barcode scanner for iPhone using phonegap?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am currently writing an application using a barcode scanner for my Final Year Project.

After doing some searching on the internet I came to this website : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

My first question is, which of the codes should I use? The one in iOS/BarcodeScanner, or the one in iPhone/BarcodeScanner? I've tried both, but I just want someone to give me a definite answer. This leads to my second question.

My second question is, upon using the codes in iOS/BarcodeScanner, my application compiles nicely, but the camera scanning refuses to show up. How do I call up the scanning function via the index.html?

If I am supposed to use the codes in iPhone/BarcodeScanner, compiling them gives me a "PGPlugin.h file missing" error. How do I go about fixing it?

I'm still new to this entire programming scene and done my fair share of googling, so please forgive me if I'm asking a question which is already answered. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi answer to first question please check this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner and follow the readme.

answer to second question :

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
function(result) {
    if (result.cancelled)
        alert("the user cancelled the scan")
    else
        alert("we got a barcode: " + result.text)
},
function(error) {
    alert("scanning failed: " + error)
}
```

)

The above link solve all the problems.